# Is there an ordering of two points in space that is stable against small perturbations? / unique parameterization for line segments?

Tags: geometry

I have the Cartesian coordinates of two points in space. (Equivalently, I have a line segment.) I need to order these two points such that small perturbations will not change the ordering. Furthermore, no pair of points will be closer than some distance epsilon. Perturbations can be assumed smaller than epsilon.   Is this possible? If so, how?

(Equivalently, is there a unique way to parameterize a line segment?)

(I don't need to order *all* points in the plane, just two at a time.  It's fine if point A < point B, point B < point C and point C < point A.)

An ordering that is *not* stable is sorting by X, then Y, then Z.   That sorts (1, 2, 7) less than (1, 3, 7), but (1.1, 2, 7) greater than (1, 3, 7).

Comment: I'm finding this super confusing. If you find you don't get any answers after a day or two, maybe try editing (or posting a brand new question) where you describe what you want this for? Also, I think you might be using 'parameterize' differently than most math folk, and your example talks about sorting point, but you asked about pairs of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round each coordinate to the nearest multiple of $2\epsilon$, so that for each point you have a unique representative $(2\epsilon a, 2\epsilon b)$that is independent of any coordinate perturbations smaller than $\pm\epsilon$.
Then impose some ordering on the integer pairs $(a,b)$, e.g. lexicographic order.
For this to work you need the two points to be at least $2\sqrt{2}\cdot\epsilon$ apart so that they don't round towards the same representative latticepoint.